# Check whether an url is text/html or other file types such as images

Tags: c#, url, header

I am writing my own C# 4.0 WPF specific web crawler. Currently I am using htmlagilitypack to process html documents.

Now the way below i am downloading the pages

```
HtmlWeb hwWeb = new HtmlWeb();
hwWeb.UserAgent = lstAgents[GenerateRandomValue.GenerateRandomValueMin(irAgentsCount, 0)];
hwWeb.PreRequest = OnPreRequest;
HtmlDocument hdMyDoc;

hwWeb = new HtmlWeb
                {
                    AutoDetectEncoding = false,
                    OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"),
                };
hdMyDoc = hwWeb.Load(srPageUrl);


        private static bool OnPreRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        return true;
    }
```

Now my question is i want to be able to determine whether given url is text/html (crawlable content) or image/pdf simply other types. How can i do that ?

Thank you very much for the answers.

C# 4.0 , WPF application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than relying on HTMLAgilityPack to download it for you, you can download the page with `HttpWebRequest` which contains a property on the `HttpWebResponse` that you can check. This would allow you to perform your check before attempting to parse the content.

Comment: +1. Consider using HEAD request first instead of GET. It will give you content-type (if supported by the server).

Comment: that is what i am asking. how to get the content type with head request ? I still can download the content with htmlagilitypack.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - I've never used HtmlAgilityPack directly (though based on the API I knew you could pass in some Html to be processed). As others have said, this doesn't appear to be possible with HtmlAgilityPack directly. Using `HtmlWebRequest` and `HtmlWebResponse` you can get the content type using the built in `ContentType` property.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - The documentation for the `ContentType` property can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contenttype.aspx).

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - `HttpWebRequest` cannot *know* the content type because it hasn't requested it yet. Once you've requested the response from the web server using `HttpWebRequest`, the response will live in an `HttpWebResponse` object. This object contains a `ContentType` property which you can use.

Answer (score 2):

You want to read the content-type in the response header.  I do not think it can be done with HtmlAgility pack from my experience with it.

Comment: that is what i am asking. how to get the content type with head request ? I still can download the content with htmlagilitypack.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used html agility pack, but I went ahead and looked at the documentation.

I see that you're setting the PreRequest field on the HtmlWeb object to a PreRequestHandler delegate.  There's also a PostResponse field that takes a PostResponseHandler delegate.  It looks like the HtmlWeb object will pass that delegate the actual response it gets from the server, in the form of a HttpWebResponse object.

However, when your code in that delegate finishes, it looks like the agility pack will continue to do whatever it would've done.  Does it throw an exception when it encounters non-html?  You may have to throw your own exception from your PostResponse function and catch it when you call Load().

As I said, I didn't try any of this.  Hope it gets you started in the right direction..